# How to handle files in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, angular, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm building an Angular + Django project, and I need to add some files to it, the idea is this model Ticket should receive some files, like imgs or pdf... Which Field should I use in the model? FileField?

```
class Ticket (models.Model):
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    estagio = models.ForeignKey(
        Estagio, related_name='tickets', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    cliente = models.ForeignKey(Cliente, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    org = models.ForeignKey(Organizacao, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    produto = models.ManyToManyField(Produto)
    valorestimado = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    termometro = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    vendedor = models.ForeignKey(
        Vendedor,  on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    vendedorext = models.ManyToManyField(
        VendedorExt, related_name='leads', blank=True)
    obs = models.ManyToManyField(Obs, related_name='tickets')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=155, blank=True, default='Aberto')
    mtvperd = models.CharField(max_length=155, null=True, blank=True)
    cmtperd = models.CharField(max_length=155, null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.ForeignKey(Created, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    updated = models.ManyToManyField(Updated)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.titulo)
```

And How can I handle this img in the view? :

```
class TicketViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Ticket.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    serializer_class = TicketSerializer
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def create(self, request):
        data = request.data

        print(data['titulo'])
        print(request.user)
        print(request.headers)

        c = Created()
        c.user = request.user
        c.save()
        V = Vendedor.objects.get(id=int(data['vendedor']))
        print(V)

        T = Ticket()
        T.titulo = data['titulo']
        T.estagio = Estagio.objects.get(id=int(data['estagio']))
        T.cliente = Cliente.objects.get(id=int(data['cliente']))
        T.org = Organizacao.objects.get(id=int(data['org']))
        T.valorestimado = int(data['valorestimado'])
        T.termometro = data['termometro']
        T.vendedor = V
        T.status = 'Aberto'

        T.created = c
        T.save()
        try:
            if data['obs'].length >= 1:
                for i in data['obs']:
                    k = Obs()
                    k.texto = i
                    k.save()
                    T.obs.add(k)
                    T.save()
        except:
            k = Obs()
            k.texto = data['obs']
            k.save()
            T.obs.add(k)
            T.save()

        produtos = data['produto']
        for prod in produtos:
            T.produto.add(Produto.objects.get(id=prod))

        T.save()
        print(data)
        return JsonResponse({'message': 'Saved'})
```

Also, is that the right way to send the file to the API?

```
  <form>
    <label id="thumbnail">
      <input type="file" name="attachments[dummy][file]"  class="file_selector" multiple="multiple"/>
    </label>
    <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="formAnexo()" style="float: right;">Salvar Anexo</button>
  </form>
```

Sorry if I miss something obvious, that's first time handling files with Django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to attach several files to the same resource I would advise to create a separate table. For instance if you want to upload several pictures to the Ticket Resource you could do:

```py
class Photo(models.Model):
    file = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='photos',
        null=False,
        max_length=100
    )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True,
        db_index=True
    )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_at']
```

and then on your ticket model define:

```py
class Ticket(models.Model):
    photos = models.ManyToManyField(
        'app_label.Photo',
        blank=True,
        related_name='ticket_photos'
    )
    ...
```

To store the photos, I would look into a solution like AWS S3 which is really easy to set up with [Django storages](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html).

In order to upload a picture on the front end with Angular, you would want to use the `FormData` API and upload data as `multipart/form-data`.

Here is a code sample:

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class MyService {

  constructor(
    private _http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  postFile(path: string, file: File, data?: any): Observable<any> {
    const uploadData = new FormData();
    uploadData.append('file', file, file.name);

    if (data) {
      Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
        uploadData.append(key, data[key]);
      });
    }
    return this._http.post(
      path,
      uploadData
    );
  }
}
```

I hope this will help you get started.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use FileUploadParser in your view.
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#basic-usage-example

```
parser_classes = (FileUploadParser,)
```

FileField for the model will be OK